# How to use Django with a legacy mysql 5.7 database (troubles with mysqlclient version)

Tags: python, mysql, django

I started a new `Django` project, but it supposed to be working with a legacy `MySQL 5.7` database.
For now, I have `Django` project, with specified database in `settings.py` and `mysqlclient` installed. First thing i tried was

```
python manage.py inspectdb --database dbname
```

but I got this error:

```
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1043, 'Bad handshake')
```

I already realized that this is because I have `mysqlconnector` for version 8.0, and it's not compatible with mysql 5.7. I also found out that when installing `mysqlconnector`, its version depends on what i have in `mysql_config`.
If I type

```
mysql_config --version
```

I get

```
8.0.30
```

And I cannot understand why, because if I run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config
```

It says that I have currently selected `mysql-5.7`.
[image: my]

What actually is `mysql_config` and why it's configured to a different version? How can I switch it to `5.7` and have right version of `mysqlclient` installed? Or are there any other ways to make `mysql 5.7` and my `Django` project work together?

Comment: Is this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62232679/13773284

Comment: no, i doesn't, It's about `mysql-connector`, but here I have `mysqlclient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was connected with different version of `libmysqlclient-dev`.

```
mneznaev@mneznaev-desktop:~$ apt list --installed | grep mysql

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libmysqlclient-dev/focal-updates,focal-security,now 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 [installed]
```

So i uninstalled it

```
sudo apt remove libmysqlclient-dev
```

Looked for another versions

```
sudo apt-cache policy libmysqlclient-dev
libmysqlclient-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
  Version table:
     8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     8.0.19-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04 500
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-5.7 amd64 Packages
```

And installed the right one

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev=5.7.39-1ubuntu18.04
```

After that i reinstalled `mysqlclient`. I use `pipenv`, so

```
pipenv uninstall mysqlclient
pipenv install mysqlclient
```

IDK whether these actions are similar to `pipenv reinstall mysqlclient` in this case.

And `bad Handshake` error has gone.

But now I have another error

```
1193, "Unknown system variable 'default_storage_engine'"
```

This is because legacy database is not actually 5.7, but 5.1. And before 5.6 this variable had another name: `storage_engine` (without `default_`)